# Store Procedure com SELECT e com o dados fazer um INSERT

Tags: sql-server

Bom dia

Estou precisando fazendo um Store Procedure onde preciso fazer um insert mas preciso puxa dados de outra tabela para incluir nesse insert.

Exemplo:

```
'''CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Corrige_Parcelas(@idPagamentoVenda int,@qtParcelas int,@prTaxaAdministracao numeric(9,2)
```

)

AS

BEGIN
 DECLARE @cont int
 DECLARE @idEmpresa int
 DECLARE @dtEmissao Date
 DECLARE @dtvenci Date
 DECLARE @vlParcela numeric(9,2)

set @cont = 1

SELECT  card.tbPagamentoVenda.idEmpresa, card.tbPagamentoVenda.dtEmissao , card.tbPagamentoVenda.vlPagamento 
FROM  card.tbPagamentoVenda
WHERE  card.tbPagamentoVenda.idFormaPagamento = @idPagamentoVenda

WHILE @cont < @qtParcelas
  BEGIN

```
 INSERT INTO card.tbParcela(idPagamentoVenda, 
                            nrParcela,
                            idEmpresa,
                            dtEmissao,
                            dtVencimento,
                            vlParcela,
                            vlTaxaAdministracao,
                            dtPagamento,
                            vlPago,
                            idStatusParcela,
                            idMovimentoBanco) 
                            VALUES(@idPagamentoVenda,
                            @cont,
                            card.tbPagamentoVenda.idEmpresa,
                            card.tbPagamentoVenda.dtEmissao,
                            DATEADD(MONTH,@cont,card.tbPagamentoVenda.dtEmissao),
                            card.tbPagamentoVenda.vlPagamento / @vlParcela,
                            (card.tbPagamentoVenda.vlPagamento * @prTaxaAdministracao)/100,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            NULL,
                            NULL)                    


SET @cont = @cont + 1   
END;
```

END;'''

Agradeço deste já.

Answer (score 0):

Você preciso utilizar o **SELECT INTO**, por exemplo:

```
SELECT dot.*
INTO tabela_final
FROM dados_outra_tabela dot
```

Organize os dados do **SELECT** igual aos dados da tabela_final (que no caso é a tabela que será inserida o resultado do **SELECT**.

Comment: Esqueci de comentar, mas tenho que mesclar com dados externos também.

Comment: Utilize o UNION ALL